# AutoRelocateFile parameter from restore-sqldatabase not recognized

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have been trying to restore a DB using the restore-sqldatabase module in powershell which seems to be working great unless there is a case of multiple data files.

To overcome this issue I was trying to use the parameter AutoRelocateFile. Below is the script which is used to perform database backup which has multiple data files.

`Restore-SqlDatabase -SqlCredential $credentialName -ServerInstance $DestinationSQLInstanceName -Database $DestinationDBName -BackupFile $BackupPath -Verbose -ReplaceDatabase -AutoRelocateFile`

This script should have replaced the existing DB in the server. However its throwing the below error.

`Restore-SqlDatabase : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AutoRelocateFile'.`

Note: Backup and restoration is happening in two different servers and backups are present in BLOB.

Update-1: Figured out the missing cmdlet, it was due to outdated module. Have updated the module and the cmdlet comes up in intellisense. However the restoration still throws an error.  Below is the current snippet.

`Restore-SqlDatabase -AutoRelocateFile  -ServerInstance $DestinationSQLInstanceName -Database $DestinationDBName  -BackupFile $BackupPath -SqlCredential $credentialName`

This is throwing the below error.

```
Restore-SqlDatabase : An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
At F:\ps_test\Backup-Restore\Restore-BLOB.ps1:543 char:10
+          Restore-SqlDatabase -AutoRelocateFile  -ServerInstance $Dest
```

The code works fine when the `-autorelocate` option is not mentioned and manually relocate the files using the `-RelocateFile` option.

Answer (score 6):

This option -AutoRelocateFile has been introduced in version [21.1.18102](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.1.18102)
so please check if you are using a proper version of the module

P.S. I saw your update. Have you removed old versions of the module?
or try to import module with -RequiredVersion option like this

Import-Module SqlServer -RequiredVersion 21.1.18102

Please try this instead if the above import does not work

```
 Install-Module -Name SqlServer -RequiredVersion 21.1.18102
```

Comment: I have updated the module and the script is throwing any error for specifying the parameter. However its throws throws the runtime error now for the same parameter.

Comment: In case anyone else has trouble: After upgrading by running "Install-Module -Name SqlServer -AllowClobber" I had to exit PowerShell and launch it again for the new module version to take effect.